# Position Of Child Object Shifted After Parenting

Tags: unity-game-engine, parent-child, unityscript

For my UIs there is this chain of hierarchy created as follow

- MainCanvas(screenspace-camera, with plane distance 0.31(near plane is 0.3))

  - EmptyPanel

    - UI_A(with rect transform)

      - UI_B(with rect transform)

Emptypanel contains a script that creates UI_A at runtime and parent UI_A to itself

```
GameObject UI_A= Instantiate(g);
UI_A.transform.position = transform.position;
UI_A.transform.SetParent(transform);
UI_A.transform.localScale = transform.localScale;
```

UI_A also contain a script that create UI_B which will attach itself to UI_A

```
//script in UI_A
void Start () {

        //float width = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;
        //float height = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;

        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos += new Vector3(offsetFromEdge.x, offsetFromEdge.y, 0f);

        _UI_B = new UI_B(transform, pos);

    }
```

and in UI_B constructor:

```
    public UI_B(Transform parent, Vector3 pos)
    {

        GameObject obj = new GameObject();
        obj.AddComponent<Canvas>();

        var comp = obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        comp.pivot = Vector2.zero;
        comp.anchorMin = Vector2.zero;
        comp.anchorMax = Vector2.zero;

        obj.transform.position = pos;

        obj.SetParent(parent);
        obj.localScale = scale;

    }
```

So, when offsetFromEdge is (0,0), UI_B appear nice at where it should be, right on top of UI_A with localPosition being  (0,0,0). However when i set the value of offsetFromEdge to (1,1), UI_B localposition become insanely huge (3611.xx, 3611.xx, 0);

These values are displayed on the RectTransform component's Pos X and Pos Y which i believe is the same a UI_B's transform.localPosition.

I have no idea what causes this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting world position of the game object first then changing its parent, that's why you are not getting desired position. You should set the parent first then set the position by transform.localposition.

Comment: Hi, editing localPosition works(since I am directly modifying the objects local position, it has to appear where I want it to be right?). However someone mentioned that when dealing with UI I should be using anchoredPosition instead, but I have no luck trying to get thing works. Any suggestion?

Comment: I have worked a lot with parenting and positioning in unity gui through C#, and it works properly without any modification of anchoredPosition also. I will suggest you to understand the concept of world coordinate system and parent coordinate system, most of the position related issues occurs due to not proper vector data set to the gameobjects regarding the coordinate system they belongs to.

Comment: Since you mentioned about the concept of world coordinate system and local coordinate system, I have a question.  For my initial example, I set the object position to be at the position of its future parent's global position before making it a child object. By right, its local position suppose to be (0,0,0), however that is not the case as I have mentioned. The child's localposition ended up at (3611.xx, 3611.xx, 0);

Comment: I have used you code given above and found many issues. See position, rotation and scale is different in different coordinate systems and when you change the coordinate system of any game objects by parenting it to a different game object then its actual local coordinates are recalculated based on how deep that game object in parent child hierarchy, and don't think if you have placed your game object at future parent game object's position it will go there, no along with position its scale will also will be taken into consideration, that is what happening in your case.

Comment: In your case you shouldn first set the parent and then change its localposition to (0,0,0) and localscale to (1,1,1). and if you want to offset its position then now will the good time to do that.

Comment: any ways (obj.SetParent(parent); obj.localScale = scale;) was throwing error so I had to change it to (obj.transform.SetParent(parent); obj.transform.localScale = parent.transform.localScale;). Its working as expected.